# Using Contact form 7 and the right side getting cut off

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming, contact-form, contact-form-7

I'm a beginner at Wordpress . Using Contact form 7 in my theme as a widget, however, it looks as if the contact form slide to the left and the right side is being cut off.
Tried different contact forms and adding CSS code changing the width from other people suggestions but none seem to work? 
Any suggestions 
www.glme.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

please change for some CSS for a footer contact form 7

```
.contact-form label { margin-bottom:3px; float:none; font-weight:700; display: block;position: relative; left: 5%; }
```

Contact page form CSS

```
#nf-form-1-cont { position: relative; left: 5%;}
```